# getting column label from a value in dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

problem:
i have a data of and i want to find out the lowest value of an indexed row
i.e

ign_data is Dataframe

```
#this returns the lowest value of the row named playstation vita
low_val=ign_data.loc['PlayStation Vita',:].min()
```

i got correct value from this line ,

but then the problem is when i am not able to get the column name in which this value is present..

i tried many things but different errors keeps on popping up

i cant understand the answers given on other places

really struggling to figure out as to which answer to select which to drop
[image: this is screenshot of data i have have and column name i want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
low_val=ign_data.loc['PlayStation Vita',:].idxmin()
```